# Decode slice of string and integers

Tags: json, go, slice

How do you decode a slice of strings and integers which don't have field names?

This is the output from the remote API I am trying to decode:

```
[["9BC67ACD", "example1", "example1.co.uk", "2018-08-06 08:46:44", "2018-08-06 08:46:44", "2018-08-06 08:46:44", "FINISHED", 1], ["B339CBA2", "example2", "example2.co.uk", "2018-08-06 08:38:25", "2018-08-06 08:38:24", "2018-08-06 08:38:27", "FINISHED", 1]]
```

I get this as a slice of bytes after doing

```
rBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
```

Can I decode this using the json decoder with `[][]interface{}`?

Comment: These are JSON arrays.

Comment: It can be decoded into a `[][] string`. Is that desired?

Comment: @leafbebop The JSON contains a JSON number, that can't be unmarshaled into `string` directly.

Comment: @icza on mobile and I didn't scroll it to the very end. I see. Still, the desired results remain unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your question:-

> Can I decode this using the json decoder with [][]interface{}

Yes you can there is nothing wrong with decoding the JSON output. This is an array of JSON.

```
[["9BC67ACD", "example1", "example1.co.uk", "2018-08-06 08:46:44", "2018-08-06 08:46:44", "2018-08-06 08:46:44", "FINISHED", 1], ["B339CBA2", "example2", "example2.co.uk", "2018-08-06 08:38:25", "2018-08-06 08:38:24", "2018-08-06 08:38:27", "FINISHED", 1]]
```

Or you can Unmarshal the JSON into an interface{}. But in both cases you need type assertion to fetch the underlying value of an interface.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

var jsonBytes string = `[["9BC67ACD", "example1", "example1.co.uk", "2018-08-06 08:46:44", "2018-08-06 08:46:44", "2018-08-06 08:46:44", "FINISHED", 1], ["B339CBA2", "example2", "example2.co.uk", "2018-08-06 08:38:25", "2018-08-06 08:38:24", "2018-08-06 08:38:27", "FINISHED", 1]]`

func main() {
    var result interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonBytes), &result); err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fetchValue(result) // This function recursively get the underlying value of an interface.
}

func fetchValue(value interface{}) {
    switch value.(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("%v is an string \n ", value.(string))
    case bool:
        fmt.Printf("%v is bool \n ", value.(bool))
    case float64:
        fmt.Printf("%v is float64 \n ", value.(float64))
    case []interface{}:
        fmt.Printf("%v is a slice of interface \n ", value)
        for _, v := range value.([]interface{}) {
            fetchValue(v)
        }
    case map[string]interface{}:
        fmt.Printf("%v is a map \n ", value)
        for _, v := range value.(map[string]interface{}) {
            fetchValue(v)
        }
    default:
        fmt.Printf("%v is unknown \n ", value)
    }
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/I6q4CPi2Gvo)

Comment: Or you can just declare `result` as `var result [][]interface{}` directly

Comment: @BarryLau Yes it will work the same. Still OP need type assertion to fetch the underlying value.